# File input frequency sorting

Tags: python-3.x

so I have to write a program that:

- Takes the filename as an argument.
- Reads the file and counts, for each band, how many albums of that band are listed in the file. (http://vlm1.uta.edu/~cconly/teaching/cse1310_spring2015/assignments/assignment7/albums.txt)
- Prints on the screen, in descending order of number of albums, a line for each band. Each line should contain the name of the band, followed by a colon and space, and then the number of albums for that band. This would look like this:

  - band1: number1
  - band2: number2
  - band3: number3

so there is my code below, but I keep getting tremendous errors that tells me that things aren't defined when they are, and I'll get this one as well --> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable, any help would be great!

```
import fileinput
import os

filename = open("albums.txt", "r") # open album.txt file 


def process_line(line):
    line = line.lower()
    new_line = ""

for letter in line:
    if letter in (""",.!"'()"""):
        continue
    elif letter == '-':
        letter = ' '

    new_line = new_line + letter

words = new_line.split()
return words    


def count_words(filename):
    if (os.path.isfile(filename) == False):
    print("\nError: file " + filename + " does not exist.\n")
    return

#in_file = open(filename, "r")


result = {}
for line in filename:
    words = process_line(line)
    for word in words:
        if (word in result):
            result[word] += 1
        else:
            result[word] = 1




def print_word_frequencies(dictionary):
    print()
    inverse = inverse_dictionary(dictionary)
    frequencies = inverse.keys()

    frequencies = list(frequencies) # convert frequencies to a list, so  that we can sort it.
frequencies.sort() # sorting the list
frequencies.reverse() # reverse the sorting of the list

for frequency in frequencies: # for words with the same frequency, we want them sorted in
    list_of_words = inverse[frequency]

    list_of_words.sort() # sorting in alphabetical order
    for word in list_of_words:
        print(word + ":", frequency)


def inverse_dictionary(in_dictionary):
    out_dictionary = {}
    for key in in_dictionary:
        value = in_dictionary[key]
        if (value in out_dictionary):
            list_of_keys = out_dictionary[value]
            list_of_keys.append(key)
        else:
            out_dictionary[value] = [key] 

return out_dictionary







def main():
    filename = "albums.txt"
    dictionary = count_words(filename)
    print_word_frequencies(dictionary)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an assignment, I will not give you the full code, but just point out some errors.

- First, your indentation is all wrong, and indentation is important in Python! This may just have happened when you pasted your code into the question editor, but maybe not. Particularly, make sure your are not mixing tabs and spaces!
- Your `count_words` method does not return anything, thus `dictionary` is `None` and you get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` in `inverse_dictionary`
- When you do `for line in filename`, you are iterating the characters in the file name, *not* the lines in the file, as the global variable `filename` is shadowed by the `filename` parameter. Open the file in that method using `with open(filename) as the_file:`
- Your `process_line` method seems odd. It seems like you remove all the special characters, but then how do you plan to separate band name and album name? You seem to just count words, not albums per band. Try `line.split(" - ")[0]` to get the band.
- All that dictionary-inversing is not needed at all. In `print_word_frequencies`, just sort the `items` from the `dictionary` using some custom `key` function to sort by the count.

With those hints, you *should* be able to fix your program. (In case you want to know, I got your program down to about ten lines of code.)